# catch an event from a message box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So my boss gaved me the project of adapting a vb.net aplication into asp.net but i never worked with asp.net before and im learning from the internet so dont blame me xD. So in my page after the login i wanted a msgbox to pop up saying "welcome" or something like that, and i managed to come across this code

```
MessageBox("Welcome to wrox forum")
Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine & _
               "window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>"
        Page.Controls.Add(lbl)
    End Sub
```

so this works fine but after the message (after the user press the ok button) i would like to redirect the user to other page but i dont know how to create the event wich will trigger after the user press "ok" any ideas? 
thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after `alert` will execute once the dialog is closed.  So just add your code at the end of the script, e.g.,

```
lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine & _
           "window.alert('" + msg + "');" & Environment.NewLine & _ 
           "document.location = 'https://www.GoHere.com';</script>"
```